# I am getting "JSON error" alert in windows phone app

Tags: cordova, windows-phone

I am getting "JSON error" alert in windows phone app when I have made Cordova app of windows. After searching this I found that it is due to pluginResult file which is present in Cordova lib. But I am not facing the same issue in Android and iOS. Please provide suggestion.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal app code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have updated all the required plugins & This issue is resolved. Thanks.